# jQuery select elements that contains text from list of strings (possible without loop?)

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to select all td elements that are within a time period of 0-3 minutes. The time format is a weird combination of words and numbers.

Right now I am able to select rows that are 0-1 minutes old like this:

```
$(".some-class td:contains('now')");
```

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
$(".some-class td:contains('now' || '1 minute' || '2 minutes')");
```

But I realize that this does not work. I am aware that there are examples in other question on how to write a loop and executing a jQuery inside the loop, adding each result to a single collection. But I was wondering if there would be a jQuery one liner that would take in multiple values and finding all elements that contains one of those values without looping manually, or without selecting multiple times and concat'ing the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [*selector group*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#grouping):

```
$(".some-class td:contains('now'), .some-class td:contains('1 minute'), .some-class td:contains('2 minutes')");
```

A selector group is a series of selectors with commas in-between. It selects elements matching any of the selectors in the group.

Comment: Sweet this is exactly what meant! Not knowing the right term just makes it very difficult google. Thanks! "selector group" it is

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(".some-class td").filter(":contains('now'), :contains('1 minute'), :contains('2 minutes')");
```